# No longer able to run photo software on XP

Tags: windows-xp

I have Olympus Master 2 and Photoimpression 6 on my system which is running with XP Pro. Both programmes ran fine till recently and neither now works. I have run Avira and AVG anti virus (only one loaded at a time), Superantispyware, Spybot and Malwarebytes and removed the usual dross but no help. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled both several times but again no help. Both programmes load but the Olympus one immediately passes to the usual 'its met a problem and needs to close'...Photoimpression loads fully but as soon as I go to the edit screen it gives the same message. I have tried another profile to no avail. Any idea why this is and what the solution is??

Comment: Try uninstall and then re-install the programs. Or consider other alternative image editing programs such as Paint.net or GIMP.

Comment: You may be able to get some useful information about the problem by looking at the system event log after one of programs fails or crashes. See [How to view and manage event logs in Event Viewer in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427) for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

from their [site](http://www.arcsoft.com/estore/software_title.asp?ProductCode=PI65):

How do I uninstall an ArcSoft application on a PC?
Answer

**Step1**: Uninstall the software in Control panel: Start-> Control Panel -> Programs -> uninstall the program, restart PC

**Step2**. Delete these files/folders (only delete these files/folders if no other ArcSoft application is installed on your machine:

XP OS:
C:\Documents and Settings\*current user*\local settings\arcsoft\
C:\Documents and Settings\*current user*\Application Data\ArcSoft\

after you have done the additional steps of removing the left over files, try the reinstall again. I would also try reinstalling [DirectX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35) as it is listed in the requirements

Comment: Hi all and thanks for the input. Martineau, the Event Viewer gives code 1000 which means little to me.Sean, I have followed your advice, although I had previously uninstalled, rebooted cleared old files and reloaded without success. Unfortunately nothing has changed except I cannot reinstall Directx using your link. It downloads but drops out on trying to install with "An internal system error occurred - please refer to DXError.log and DirectX.log to determine problem. Needless to say on looking at those it wasn't clear to me what the problem was. Any ideas?

Comment: As a follow up I have managed to get Olympus Master 2 loaded and running in compatability mode (Windows 2000). Strange as it used to run in XP, but at least its now running.